# m2eclipse exclude unnecessary folders

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I've a multi-module Maven project. When I use the m2eclipse plugin to import the project into Eclipse. All folders in the parent directory will be imported as plain folder, but they will be imported as sub Java projects at the same time. Thus while typing file names to open, the result will contain duplicate entries. It's very annoying.

---

**Is there a way to exclude unnecessary folders in Eclipse?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer, just right click on the project and select properties, and select resources. Select the "Resource Filters". That's exactly what I need.